# How to have a subview displayed in all controller ? Like a navbar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a kind of navigation bar but without the navigation bar element.
So I created a view controller with his xib. it's like a footer. I want this footer to be displayed in the entire app. But when I switch view with the navigation controller, this footer is reallocated and is being part of the transition animation. Logic because I init this footer in all Views Controller.

I would like to have the same display as a navigation bar (a bottom bar persistent in the app).
How I could do it and where ?

Here is how I start my app:

```
LHHomeViewController *rootViewController = [[LHHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LHHomeViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

[nav setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom `UINavigationController class` file & assign this class to your `UINavigationController` as you do with normal `UIViewController`.

Then write your code for custom nav bar here & add it to view of Navigation controller using
`[self.view addSubview:view_to_add]` method. By using this you can keep your view on top all the times.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of the [View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html).

Essentially you want to create some sort of UIViewController subclass where you house your custom bottom bar but you also initialise it with a rootViewController which could be your NavigationController.

You would then position the rootViewController and your custom bottom bar inside your view controller subclass to get the desired layout.